# El componentDidMount() no me funciona con mi API en Node, si me a ese mismo componentDidMount() le doy la url de una api externa me funciona

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

1. Me pinta los dato en consola solo si viene de una Api externa, solo 
          quiero que me devuelva el get de todos los usuarios . En el 
          localhost:5000/pe me devuelve todos los usuarios ,pero cuando lo pido en 
          react me dice que el fetch ha fallado . Gracias

   ````
   ```React
   ```Node.js
   ````

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import "./index.css";
   import Formulario from './Formulario';


   interface IState {
     data: any[]
   }



   class App extends React.Component<any, IState>{
     constructor(props: any) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
         data: []
       }
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       fetch('http://localhost:5000/pe')
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then((data) => {
           this.setState({ data })
         })
         .catch(console.log)
     }

     render() {

       const { data } = this.state;
       console.log(data)

       return (
         <>
           <Formulario />
         </>
       )
     }
   }

   export default App;

   // Aqui esatria NodeJS con MongoDB

   const express = require("express");
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
   const passport = require('passport');
   const Keys = require('./config/keys');
   const User = require('./models/User')

   require('./services/passport');


   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users',
       { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
       (err, res) => {
           if (err) {
               throw err;
           }

           server.listen(5000, () => console.log("Conexion a la Base de Datos 
   Correcta"))
       })

   const server = express();

   // Aqui indicamos cuando queremos que epxire nuestra clave y que la 
   codifique con el metodo que le pasamos
   server.use(
       cookieSession({
           maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Esto equivael a 30 dias ya que 
   lo pasamos a milisegundos
           keys: [Keys.cookieKey]
       })
   );


   server.use(passport.initialize());
   server.use(passport.session()); 

   require('./routes/authRoutes')(server);
   ```
2. ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   const passport = require('passport');
   const User = require('../models/User')

   module.exports = server => {

   // este get es la peticion de token
     server.get('/auth/google',
       passport.authenticate('google', {
         scope: ['profile', 'email']
       })
     );

   server.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'));

   server.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
       res.send(req.user);
     });

   // Cerramos sesion
     server.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
       req.logout();
       res.send(req.user);
     });

   ```
     // Devolvemos todos lo usuarios
     server.get('/pe', (req, res) => {
       User.find({}).sort({ '_id': -1 }).exec((err, notas) => {
         if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error en el servidor' 
    });

         // Devolvemos el resultado de la query en json
         if (notas) {
           return res.status(200).send({
             notas
           });
         } else {
           return res.status(404).send({
             message: 'No hay notas'
           });
         }
       });
     })
   };
   ```

   - En esta ultima query es la que me devuelve todos los datos

Comment: que error te envía esto? `.catch(console.log)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error podria ser que: `componentDidMount` debe de ser una funcion `async`(asyncrona), ya que utilizas `fetch` de javascript, eso conlleva a que utilices `promesas`, por lo tanto tu funcion deberia de estar definida asi:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/pe')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
}
```

Aunque te aconsejaría que esperes la respuesta del servidor y confirmar que la petición sea correcta, algo como esto:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    try{
        let res = await fetch(`${url}/api/sustancia`)
        let data = await res.json()
        if(res.ok){
            this.setState({
                sustancias:data,
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log("error")
        }

    }
    catch(error){
        this.setState({
            error:error
        })
    }
}
```